# Best async practices for Jade template pages created from objects in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have this website run on node.js using jade for page templates and mongodb to store some data. One of the pages is this 'parts' page. It is just a list of parts I use in some project, but that's not important.

So i have this scenario where:

1. I add an object in the form of a doc to the DB
2. That updates a global array of those objects
3. That global array gets passed to the jade template which draws the list for each element in the global array of objects.

On server startup, should the server ever restart, it populates the global by querying the DB once.

Here's my question,
Is this the best practice I can use in an async environment like node?
My rational is that i'm reducing the amount of time spent communicating with the DB by keeping the docs in the app.

Would it be better to query the DB for the docs and pass that to the template each time a user loads a page?

is using a global like this even async or just too fast to tell?

note: it's only for few records; say less then 200 records.
note: there will never be more than 1 person adding to the array at a time.

edit: third option, is this method bad all together?

Comment: tl;dr: If it works and you're happy with it, good enough! Using the global sounds fine to me if you aren't concerned about memory use with a small data set. If every query absolutely must use current data you have to think about a race condition where a user requests the data before your database saves the new parts list and updates your global. With a small database like this, storing it in memory or querying it on each request are probably both very fast and resource cheap. Usually you would query on each request because queries are often customized and you want current state.

Comment: PS if you like, you can compare the latency cost of the database lookup with a web browser - firebug and chrome's F12 console have views to show the timing of the request/response cycle. So you can see that e.g. it takes 100ms latency to reach the server, 50ms wait while the server generates a response, 100ms return latency, 125ms to render the page.

Especially if the database server is on the same machine as Node, the database latency is likely insignificant for your small dataset